# PG::SyntaxError when joins relation with default_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Ruby on Rails 4.0.1.

Church, Campus, Households classes inherit by STI from Group class.

Group class has default_scope

```
scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }
default_scope active
```

This

> Church.last.campuses.joins(:households).to_sql

Gives such sql:

```
SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups" INNER JOIN "groups" "households_groups" ON "households_groups"."parent_group_id" = "groups"."id" AND "households_groups"."type" IN ('Household') AND "groups"."type" IN ('Household'), "groups"."active" = 't' WHERE "groups"."active" = 't' AND "groups"."type" IN ('Campus') AND "groups"."parent_group_id" = $1
```

and it causes an error:

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "="
LINE 1: ...roups"."type" IN ('Household'), "groups"."active" = 't' WHER...
```

there should be "AND" instead of comma before "groups"."active".

Is there an any way to avoid this bug and keep default_scope?

Comment: It seems an ActiveRecord bug to me; did you try to report it to [Rails issues](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues)?

Comment: I've just created an issue https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/15087

Comment: Well, it was better to read [Rails issue reporting guideline](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html#reporting-an-issue) first... I would suggest you to read it and adjust your issue, otherwise expect a bit of anger, or even worse indifference...

Comment: You're right, I've closed the issue and will update it in a free while.